# Symbol Of Differential Operators

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

When we are given a differential operator of the form
$Lf : = \sum_\alpha a_{\alpha}(x) D^ \alpha f(x) $ , we can define the symbol associated with it to be the function:
$a(x,y) := \sum_\alpha a_\alpha (iy)^\alpha  $  .

We then can consider an operator (in divergence form) on $L^2 (\Omega) $, given formally by: 
$ Hf := -b(x)^{-1} \sum_{i,j=1}^{N} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \{a_{i,j} (x) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \} $ .

Davies' book - "Spectral Theory of differential operators" says :
"The reader will observe that the operator $H$ defined above is not that associated with the symbol $a(x,y) := b(x)^{-1} \sum_{i.j=1}^{N} a_{i,j} (x) y_i y_j $ according to the procedure above and then gives the following exercise:
Write down the symbol, in the first sense, associated with the operator $H$ , assuming the coefficients $a_{i,j} (x) $ are $C^1 $ functions of $x$ .

Can someone explain me what does he mean by that?
What should I do in this question and how can I find this form?

Any detailed answer might help ! 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why do you have $i$ in there? Shouldn't it be: $a(x,y) := \sum_\alpha a_\alpha (y)^\alpha  $.

Comment: No .... This is the definition the book has...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Expand $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(a_{i,j}(x) \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\right) $

Comment: Your point is that I need to transform the divergence form into the reguler one?

Answer (score 1):

$H$ is given in divergence form, $L$ is not.